# Fancybox vs autocompletion

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fancybox, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to add autocompletetion and fancybox at the same page:

```
<?php //automcomplete // ?>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">

<?php //fancybox //?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */ 
        $(document).ready(function() { $.noConflict();
        $("#various3").fancybox({
                'width'         : '95%',
                'height'        : '95%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            })


        });
    /* ]]> */ 
    </script>
```

it seems that there is a conflict, but noconflict didn't work for me :(
i"ve two question:
1-is there any simple mean and simplier to add these two functionality (i found that the .js are numerous, it can make my page slower with all these query? (i'm thinking in addition to add a slider--> more jquery!)
2-how to make fancybox work with autocompletion?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single instance of jQuery should work for both plugins, ideally the latest version so you could remove this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```